# NServiceBus worker unregistration not working

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor, nservicebus5

I'm trying to unregister a worker node as described [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/disconnect-workers), but the procedure doesn't seem to work correctly. If the distributor has any control messages related to the disconnecting worker when running the unregistration script, next time messages come in, it will consume those (effectively sending more work to the node). It's only afterwards that the distributor will reject control messages coming from the node.

Has anyone got this to work correctly = the worker should not receive any new messages RIGHT AFTER unregistration?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the intended behaviour for the `unregister` operation. It was designed and implemented like that.

It does not actively remove the existing ready messages for the worker from the distributors storage queue. It only makes sure that the worker will not send any new ready messages back to, and thus request more work from, the distributor after the unregister.

Comment: So when is it safe to stop the worker for maintenance, making sure there's no messages in its queue? Our requirement is that we can't delay message processing while we service the worker (5 mins or so)